# como hacer una subconsulta en controlador ASP C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp, subconsultas

Tengo la siguiente relacion en mi bd

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que intento es mandar un Json con la informacion de equipo entre esos datos Nombre tipo

hasta ahora solo logre llegar a Marca y sus atributos este es mi codigo

```
            var Lista = db.Eq_tblEquipos.Select(a => new
        {
            a.id,
            a.NoSerie,
            a.Ip,
            Marca = a.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos.Marca,
            Modelo = a.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos.Modelo,
            a.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id,
            tipo_equipo = db.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos.Select(b => new { tipo = b.Eq_tblTipoEquipos.NombreTipo  }),
          
            //,
            a.Etiqueta,
            a.Status,
            ubicacion = a.Eq_tblUbicaciones.area,
            a.FechaIngreso,
            a.FechaCambio,
            a.FechaGaranriaInicio,
            a.FechaGarantiaFin,
            a.TipoIngreso,
            a.Donado
        }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero poder ayudarte.
La consulta la haría de esta forma, y posterior usar la librería Newtonsoft.Json para convertir a json el resultado de la consulta. Espero te sea de ayuda.

```
var datos = (from t in db.Tipo
                         join m in db.MarcaEquipo on t.Id equals m.tipo_id
                         join e in db.Equipo on m.Id equals e.marca_id
                         //where m.Marca==""
                         select new {Equipo=t.nombreTipo,Marca=m.Marca }
                       ).ToList();
            var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datos);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte es exactamente lo que necesitaba

Comment: @user252138, fue un gusto poder ayudarte mi estimado!